# NuGet.Config isn't updated by the nuget CLI sources command

Tags: c#, nuget

I created a nuget package using `dotnet pack`, and turned a local directory into a feed using

```
nuget sources add -Name My.Namespace -Source /full/path/to/the/packages
```

and then added the package to the feed

```
nuget add bin/Debug/My.Namespace.0.0.0.nupkg -source /full/path/to/the/packages
```

`nuget sources list` shows this local feed as expected:

```
Registered Sources:

  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  2.  My.Namespace [Enabled]
      /full/path/to/the/packages
```

and the directory structure of `packages` is correct

```
/full/path/to/the/packages
└── my.namespace
    └── 0.0.0
        ├── my.namespace.0.0.0.nupkg
        ├── my.namespace.0.0.0.nupkg.sha512
        └── my.namespace.nuspec
```

But `dotnet` repeatedly fails to add the package to projects

```
$ dotnet add package My.Namespace
error: Unable to find package My.Namespace. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
error: Package 'My.Namespace' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project '~/Documents/Projects/dotnet-core-api/Fun.Project.csproj'.
```

And manually adding the package to the `.csproj` errors when I try to build:

```
error NU1101: Unable to find package My.Namespace. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
```

Looks like `dotnet` isn't checking my local NuGet feeds, so I inspected `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config` which only contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>                                                                                                                                             
</configuration>
```

Why isn't my local feed here?

How can I get it to appear here? (Ideally so that I won't have to manually edit this file every time...)

Or, if the reason I can't add my package to my other project is unrelated, how am I meant to locally create and depend on NuGet packages?

Answer (score 1):

The command line to add a package source will, by default, add it to the file in the path `%appdata%\NuGet\nuget.config`. If you want to modify a specific Nuget config file, you can specify which one by using the `-ConfigFile` option, for example:

```
nuget sources add -Name My.Namespace -ConfigFile /path/to/config -Source /path/to/packages
```

I'm making a guess that Nuget is finding the config file in `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config` and stops searching for more.

Note, if the Nuget configuration you require is only specific to the project you are working with, then I would recommend placing a `nuget.config` file in the root of your solution folder.

You can find info on the config file locations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses).

Comment: Indeed `nuget sources add ... -Config ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config ...` added the source to the config file, and now all my `dotnet` commands work. I wonder why this file isn't updated automatically? The Microsoft docs clearly state this is the default config file

Comment: This is why I prefer to use project-specific config files. It also helps with CI/CD because the build system can also locate the packages.